# Laravel and Backbone.js router issue

Tags: backbone.js, laravel, router, pushstate

I am working on a Laravel project with Backbone.js and I am stuck with router issues. I want my Laravel project to be a Single Page App (SPA), so at Backbone.js side, I am using hash fragments for links, but Laravel's Route is not recognise my Backbone's hash signs.

I understand that there is also `pushState` alternative for this purpose.
How can I use routers for a Single Page App, for both server and client side?

Answer (score 0):

When you use Backbone.js you communicate the server through its API. In your Laravel project just create a RESTful API, so you can GET and POST data from/for it. In Laravel you use only models representing the resource and controllers handling the API requests. The routes for these API controllers don't have to care about hashtags, they are just regular routes. In the Backbone client all you have to do is to set the API URLs in your models to your resources in your Laravel back end, then you can fetch and use them.